# 2 type of users, 1? session controller in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a system with 2 types of users. Buyers and Sellers. After some thought i decided to make completely separated models for these(dont know yet if that was good idea)

I now need to build a session controller and thinking these should be separate as well. One for each model.

BUT then im thinking. If a logged in Buyer by accident hits part of the Seller area, the seller controller would check if logged in (and since the user is not seller it would be no),  then redirect to the login for the seller, which would be very confusing for the buyer. (did that make sense?)

Should it be split up to 2 separate applications sharing the same database?

Any recommendations?

Comment: You want a `User` class, and have the `Buyer` and `Seller` classes both inherit from that.  One application would be best, as there will need to be interaction between the buyers and sellers.

Comment: I was actually starting out like that. Read some about the Single Table Inheritance which I ended up not thinking would be the best. Then i went on with User class and "inheritance" by using belongs_to which made me dizzy sometime when thees got relations as well.

Comment: Could you post some more complete examples of your models and their fields and relationships, otherwise won't be able to help much more.

Comment: STI is only really bad if there is hardly anything in common between the models, but this can be mitigated.

Comment: I will do some more investigation on inheritance + rails and see if i can fit it together. Probably be back, thanks so far

Comment: I was thinking STI would be bad if both seller and buyer would have connection to a class named Category. Seller can only have one category but buyer can be interested in many categories. They would be sharing some attributes like address fields, email.